# Axios call runs twice in react functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why does this fetched print twice? When the axios call is put outside the function it only runs once.

```
function App() {
  axios('https://www.google.com/').then(x => 
      console.log("fetched")
  )

  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: look into "useEffect" hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in a `useEffect` hook.

```
function App() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios('https://www.google.com/').then(x => 
        console.log("fetched")
    )
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: But I want it to run every time it renders and not after the component renders but before.

Comment: If you want to run it every time it re-renders, you need to remove the second parameter of the useEffect function, the `, []` part.
Also, axios sends out an HTTP request, which is handled asynchronously. There's no need to first render your component when a value is returned. However, you can implement a loading state.

Comment: Okay, but why does it run twice in my original code though?

Comment: Because every time a re-render is caused, everything within that function will be executed again. Hooks however, know if they have been registered or not. And you can't duplicate a hook by re-rendering.

Comment: But there isn't anything that would make it render twice.

Comment: Do you have React Strict Mode enabled? This causes the component to be rendered twice.

Comment: I did. I removed it and it now behaves as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a call to run only one time when the component is rendered, you should put it inside a useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios('https://www.google.com/').then(x => 
      console.log("fetched")
  );
},[]);
```

Comment: But I want it to run every time it renders.

Comment: @sdafsdf32 that's what it currently does

Comment: No it only runs on mount.

Comment: so you need to remove the array of dependencies from the useEffect